# Generate JSON dictionary from recursive scrapy functions

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am running the scrapy spider on airbnb for academic purposes below. I scrape all listings first

(such as: https://www.airbnb.com/s/Berlin--Germany/homes?tab_id=all_tab&query=Berlin%2C%20Germany&place_id=ChIJAVkDPzdOqEcRcDteW0YgIQQ&checkin=2020-05-01&adults=1&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&checkout=2020-05-02)

to get their ids and then go to the listing's page

(such as: https://www.airbnb.de/rooms/20839690?location=Berlin&check_in=2020-05-01&check_out=2020-05-02&adults=1)

and get the geo-data from the details JSON. Ideally, I would like to have a final JSON nested like:

> {{'ID': ID1, 'Title': Title1, 'Latitude': Lat1},{'ID': ID2, 'Title': Title2, 'Latitude': Lat2}}

Because of the recursive structure, I have the full list of title, price etc. already in the first go, while lng and lat are only one element per loop run.

> {{Price1, Price2, Price3..., id1, id2...lng1, lat1}, {Price1, Price2, Price3..., id1, id2..., lng2, lat2}}

Any idea how I can restructure the code to get the above structure?

Cheers 
marcello

Spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from airbnb.items import AirbnbItem
import json
import pprint

all_ids = []
detail = {}

class AirbnbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'airbnb_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.com', 'airbnb.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.airbnb.de/s/Berlin/homes?checkin=2020-05-01&checkout=2020-05-02&adults=1']


    def parse(self, response):
        item = AirbnbItem()

        for listing in response.xpath('//div[@class = "_fhph4u"]'):
            detail["title"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@aria-label').extract()
            detail["price"] = listing.xpath('//span[@class = "_1p7iugi"]/text()').extract()
            detail["rating"] = listing.xpath('//span[@class = "_3zgr580"]/text()').get()
            detail["id"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@target').extract()
            #item["link"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@href').extract()

            x_id = [i.split('_')[1] for i in detail['id']]
            detail['id'] = x_id

            for i in x_id:
                link = 'https://www.airbnb.de/api/v2/pdp_listing_details/'+i+'?_format=for_rooms_show&_p3_impression_id=p3_1587291065_1e%2FBlC2IefkrfTQe&adults=1&check_in=2020-05-01&check_out=2020-05-02&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&'
                yield scrapy.Request(url = link, callback =self.parse_detail)


    def parse_detail(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

        detail["lat"] = jsonresponse["pdp_listing_detail"]["lat"]
        detail["lng"] = jsonresponse["pdp_listing_detail"]["lng"]

        return detail
```

Items

```
import scrapy

class AirbnbItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    id = scrapy.Field()
    rating = scrapy.Field()
    lat = scrapy.Field()
    lng = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information to the to the `parse_detail` method and yield from there

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = AirbnbItem()

    for listing in response.xpath('//div[@class = "_fhph4u"]'):
        detail["title"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@aria-label').get()
        detail["price"] = listing.xpath('//span[@class = "_1p7iugi"]/text()').get()
        detail["rating"] = listing.xpath('//span[@class = "_3zgr580"]/text()').get()
        detail["id"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@target').get()
        #item["link"] = listing.xpath('//a[@class = "_i24ijs"]/@href').get()

        detail['id'] = detail['id'].split('_')[1]

        link = 'https://www.airbnb.de/api/v2/pdp_listing_details/'+detail['id']+'?_format=for_rooms_show&_p3_impression_id=p3_1587291065_1e%2FBlC2IefkrfTQe&adults=1&check_in=2020-05-01&check_out=2020-05-02&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&'
        yield scrapy.Request(url = link, 
                meta={'item': detail}, #pass information to the next method
                callback =self.parse_detail)


def parse_detail(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

    detail = response.meta['item']
    detail["lat"] = jsonresponse["pdp_listing_detail"]["lat"]
    detail["lng"] = jsonresponse["pdp_listing_detail"]["lng"]

    yield detail
```

BTW, Item class is useless, do not use it.

Comment: Thanks! There is a problem with this line ```detail['id'] = .split('_')[1]
``` giving me an invalid sytax error

Comment: @marcellobello check now

Comment: It gives me ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split ```. This was why I was positing originally. Because of the way I run the loop I have a list of all ids already. Is there a way to only read one id then pass on to the parse_detail function. Then run parse to get the next id, pass on again to parse_detail etc. ?

Comment: @marcellobello did u copy all all code jnto your file? Looks like you didnt..

Comment: Apologies! I skipped one line. But the code runs for only the first element now?

Comment: ```[{"title": "Cozy room in the heart of Berlin (Neuk\u00f6lln)", "price": "33\u20ac", "rating": "4.65", "id": "19977266", "lat": 52.4785, "lng": 13.44535}
]```

Comment: @marcellobello do you see the word “duplicate” in logs?

Comment: no and no further anomalies. It takes the first id parses the details and finishes

Comment: Maybe that yield is outside the for loop, not properly identeted

Comment: yield scrapy.request is in the for loop. Whether it being in or out does not affect the result